# Are there any custom views available for Grafana or maybe any editor for the views?

Tags: openshift

we have some OpenShift containers with some services on it. And we want to monitor the status with Grafana. Could you please help with finding some of the editors to crate some custom views.

Comment: with Q as (
select AVG(pc.price) as AVGprice, pc.model, p.maker from PC pc 
JOIN product p 
on pc.model = p.model AND p.maker = 'A'
UNION ALL
select AVG(lt.price), lt.model, p.maker from laptop lt 
JOIN product p 
on lt.model = p.model AND p.maker = 'A') 
select AVG(Q.AVGprice) as AVGPrice from Q

Comment: select AVG(pc.hd) 
from PC pc
where pc.model in 
(select model from Product prd where prd.type in ('PC','Printer'))

Comment: param($minutes = 60)

$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $minutes; $i++) {
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
  $myshell.sendkeys(".")
}

Comment: https://join.skype.com/mNeleC8DI99I

Comment: Json and Json massive work with in postgre: and (application_body -> 'requiredFields' ->>'loanAmount')::decimal < 50000
and (application_body -> 'nonpayrollClientRequiredFields' ->> 'positionCategory')::text like '%cm.PersonJobTitleCode.BusinessOwner%'

Comment: SELECT
 nvl(
     (SELECT decode(id_obj,NULL,'нет данных',id_obj) -- если поле id_obj is null значит выводим нет данных
      FROM obj
     WHERE  id_obj = 2320395) 
 ,'нет данных')  -- если вообще нету записей с таким ID в таблцие то выводим нет данных
FROM dual;